# Get list of XPaths of elements

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xpath

I have NodeList of elements with specific name and I would like to have XPath of all of theese nodes.

I cannot find a way how to do that.

```
NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("definition");
 for (int i = 0; i < nList.getLength(); i++) {
 Node node = nList.item(i);
 System.out.println(node.GET_XPATH());
}
```

I'm looking for a method like GET_XPATH()

Do someone know how to do that? Or is it even possible?

If it is possible with XSLT can use it as well, but prefer if someone know about this possibility in Java.

REASON:
I need a set of pointers to XML library. Pointers to definition elements.

EXAMPLE
Input:

```
<odML>
    <section>
        <type>experiment</type>
        <name>Experiment</name>
        <definition></definition>
        <property>
            <definition></definition>
        </property>
        <property>
            <definition></definition>
            <value>
                <definition></definition>
            </value>
        </property>
    </section>
    <definition></definition>
</odML>
```

Output:

```
/odML/section/definition

/odML/section/property[1]/definition

/odML/section/property[2]/definition

/odML/section/property[2]/value/definition

/odML/definition
```

Comment: I'm sorry what?  xPath is query language used to execute queries against a document or node...I'm not sure what you're hoping to achieve

Comment: I need a reverse process. I have a set of XML and I need for every of this XML have a list of XPaths to definition elements... Definition elements are supposed to be almost everywhere in the document. And I need to know that in XML XYZ have this element  on /odML/section/property[1]/definition for example...

Comment: In some editors you are able to right click on any element you can get a XPath for this element. Lets say that I need to do similiar function if the first comment is unclear.

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty sure you're going to need to build this yourself (or there might be a library which can help), but I'm pretty sure it's not in the default libraries

Comment: This is *probably* possible in XSLT. We'll know for sure when you post an example of the input XML and the expected output.

Comment: Added example with simplified XML

Comment: Is the name "definition" supposed to be hard-coded into this?

Comment: Yes. This is stable element name and I need list only of theese elements.

Comment: Ondrej, As you can see, the XSLT solution is much shorter (just 18 lines) and simpler than a solution in Java. XSLT is the language especially designed for processing XML, and it shows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/"> 
    <xsl:for-each select="//definition">
        <xsl:for-each select="ancestor::*">
            <xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
            <xsl:if test="(preceding-sibling::*|following-sibling::*)[name()=name(current())]">
                <xsl:text>[</xsl:text>  
                <xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::*[name()=name(current())]) + 1"/>
                <xsl:text>]</xsl:text>  
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:text>/definition</xsl:text>    
        <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>  
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>  

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied to your example input, will return:

```
/odML/section/definition
/odML/section/property[1]/definition
/odML/section/property[2]/definition
/odML/section/property[2]/value/definition
/odML/definition
```

Answer (score 1):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="definition">
     <xsl:apply-templates select="ancestor-or-self::*" mode="path"/>
     <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*" mode="path">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('/',name())"/>
    <xsl:if test="../*[name()=name(current())][2]">
        <xsl:value-of select=
        "concat('[',count(preceding-sibling::*[name()=name(current())])+1,']')"/>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied on the provided source XML document**:

```
<odML>
    <section>
        <type>experiment</type>
        <name>Experiment</name>
        <definition></definition>
        <property>
            <definition></definition>
        </property>
        <property>
            <definition></definition>
            <value>
                <definition></definition>
            </value>
        </property>
    </section>
    <definition></definition>
</odML>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
/odML/section/definition
/odML/section/property[1]/definition
/odML/section/property[2]/definition
/odML/section/property[2]/value/definition
/odML/definition
```